# How to make a DateIntervalType field in Symfony form not required

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have a DateIntervalType field:

```
    $builder
        ->add('effort', DateIntervalType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'integer',
            'input' => 'dateinterval',
            'with_years' => false,
            'with_months' => false,
            'with_days' => false,
            'with_hours' => true,
            'with_minutes' => true,
        ]);
```

If I submit the form I get the error message that it is invalid if I leave the hours and minutes empty. I have no constraints for the entity attribute (no `@Assert\NotBlank()` or anything like that) and it is nullable:

```
class Template
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="dateinterval", nullable=true)
     */
     private $effort;

    // ...
}
```

The submitted values are:

```
"effort" => [▼
    "hours" => ""
    "minutes" => ""
]
```

I want to submit the form without values and without getting this error.

Comment: Did you try to set `input` to `string`?

Comment: I will try in the evening, thank you for now!

Comment: @qdequippe That's not exactly what I'm searching for. But you helped me to find a solution: `'widget'      => 'text', 'input'    => 'dateinterval',`. Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you

Comment: great! that's ok, answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not get errors if you change `widget` from `integer` to `text`:

```
$builder
    ->add('effort', DateIntervalType::class, [
        // ...
        'widget' => 'text',
        // ...
    ]);
```